# python list of dictionaries find paired values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have this csv containing some paired rows such as:

```
LabebStoreId,catalog_uuid,lang,cat_0_name,cat_1_name,cat_2_name,cat_3_name,catalogname,description,properties,price,price_before_discount,externallink,Rating,delivery,discount,instock
6021,89028,en,Electronics & Appliances,Batteries & Power,Batteries,Alkaline Batteries,Energizer Max AA Alkaline Battery E91BP Pack of 8,,"{""Number of batteries included"": ""8"", ""Battery voltage"": ""1.5""}",41.5,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028,,,,
6021,89028,ar,الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية,البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة,بطاريات,بطاريات الكالاين,ENERGIZER BATTERY AAX8 MAX,,"{""Number of batteries included"": ""8"", ""طاقة البطارية"": ""1.5""}",41.5,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028,,,,
6021,742553,en,Electronics & Appliances,Batteries & Power,Batteries,Alkaline Batteries,Energizer Max AAA Alkaline Battery EP2BP Pack of 8,,"{""Number of batteries included"": ""8"", ""Battery voltage"": ""1.5""}",33.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553,,,,
6021,742553,ar,الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية,البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة,بطاريات,بطاريات الكالاين,ENERGIZER AAA/8 MAX ALKALINE,,"{""Number of batteries included"": ""8"", ""طاقة البطارية"": ""1.5""}",33.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553,,,,
6021,893379,en,Electronics & Appliances,Large Appliances,Fridges,Fridge 101L to 200L,First1 Free Standing 2 shelves Fridge FR-130L,,"{""Dimensions WxDxH"": ""W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm""}",549.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379,,Free delivery,,1.0
6021,893379,ar,الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية,أجهزة منزلية كبيرة,الثلاجات,ثلاجة 101L إلى 200L,FIRST1 FR-130L FRIDGE,,"{""Dimensions WxDxH"": ""W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm""}",549.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379,,,,1.0
6021,915909,en,Electronics & Appliances,Batteries & Power,Power Adaptors & Sockets,Adaptors & Sockets,Elexon Universal Travel Adaptor PP7974A White,,{},14.5,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/adaptors-sockets/elexon-universal-travel-adaptor/p/915909,,,,
6021,945671,en,Electronics & Appliances,Small Appliances,Food Preparation,Rice Cooker,Mychoice Rice Cooker 350W F-06RC White,,{},69.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671,,,,
6021,945671,ar,الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية,أجهزة منزلية صغيرة,تحضير الطعام,طبخ الأرز,جهاز طهي الأرز الأول F-06RC 350 وات 0.6 لتر,,{},69.0,,https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671,,,,
```

one row for English and one for Arabic and I'd like to setup some check like this:

```
if catalog_uuid contains en and ar:
   payload = {
            "row": {
                "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                "lang": d["lang"],
                "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                "description": d["description"],
                "properties": d["properties"],
                "price": d["price"],
                "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                "externallink": d["externallink"],
                "Rating": d["Rating"],
                "delivery": d["delivery"],
                "discount": d["discount"],
                "instock": d["instock"],
                
            }
        }
   payload = {
            "nextRow": {
                "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                "lang": d["lang"],
                "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                "description": d["description"],
                "properties": d["properties"],
                "price": d["price"],
                "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                "externallink": d["externallink"],
                "Rating": d["Rating"],
                "delivery": d["delivery"],
                "discount": d["discount"],
                "instock": d["instock"],
                
            }
        }
elif catalog_uuid contains only en:
   payload = {
            "row": {
                "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                "lang": d["lang"],
                "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                "description": d["description"],
                "properties": d["properties"],
                "price": d["price"],
                "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                "externallink": d["externallink"],
                "Rating": d["Rating"],
                "delivery": d["delivery"],
                "discount": d["discount"],
                "instock": d["instock"],
                
            }
        }
elif catalog_uuid contains only ar:
   payload = {
            "row": {
                "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                "lang": d["lang"],
                "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                "description": d["description"],
                "properties": d["properties"],
                "price": d["price"],
                "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                "externallink": d["externallink"],
                "Rating": d["Rating"],
                "delivery": d["delivery"],
                "discount": d["discount"],
                "instock": d["instock"],
                
            }
        }
```

some rows only contains English and some only contains Arabic so I have to cover both aspects. I am using pandas to read the csv and transforming the dataframe to `pd.to_json(orient="index")` because I need to post that rows in a POST request as a json.

Here is my recent try:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import ast


HEADERS = {"Accept": "*/*", "Content-Type": "application/json"}


df = pd.read_csv("carrefour-uae-items-final.csv").fillna("").astype(str)
dict_data = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="index"))
list_dict = [d for d in dict_data.values()]


for d in list_dict:
    cat_id = d["catalog_uuid"]
    if next(item for item in list_dict if item["catalog_uuid"] == cat_id):
        payload_rows = ["row", "nextRow"]
        for row in payload_rows:
            payload = {
                row: {
                    "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                    "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                    "lang": d["lang"],
                    "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                    "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                    "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                    "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                    "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                    "description": d["description"],
                    "properties": d["properties"],
                    "price": d["price"],
                    "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                    "externallink": d["externallink"],
                    "Rating": d["Rating"],
                    "delivery": d["delivery"],
                    "discount": d["discount"],
                    "instock": d["instock"],
                    "images": ast.literal_eval(d["encoded_images"]),
                }
            }
            print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4))
            response = requests.post(
                "http://crawlerapi.labeb.com/api/PCCrawler/Crawl?StoreId=6021",
                headers=HEADERS,
                json=payload,
            )
            print(response.content.decode())
    else:
        payload = {
            "row": {
                "LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"],
                "catalog_uuid": d["catalog_uuid"],
                "lang": d["lang"],
                "cat_0_name": d["cat_0_name"],
                "cat_1_name": d["cat_1_name"],
                "cat_2_name": d["cat_2_name"],
                "cat_3_name": d["cat_3_name"],
                "catalogname": d["catalogname"],
                "description": d["description"],
                "properties": d["properties"],
                "price": d["price"],
                "price_before_discount": d["price_before_discount"],
                "externallink": d["externallink"],
                "Rating": d["Rating"],
                "delivery": d["delivery"],
                "discount": d["discount"],
                "instock": d["instock"],
                "images": ast.literal_eval(d["encoded_images"]),
            }
        }

        print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4))

        response = requests.post(
            "http://crawlerapi.labeb.com/api/PCCrawler/Crawl?StoreId=6021",
            headers=HEADERS,
            json=payload,
        )
        print(response.content.decode())
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how to achieve the above logic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is the problem? The above code doesn't function?

Comment: No code is working but it is not pairing like the above pseudo code for example if `catalog_uuid` contains both version of lang which is `en` and `ar` I want to send the payload like this `{"row": {"LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"], ...}}`  `{"nextRow": {"LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"], ...}}` and if `catalog_uuid` only contains one lang code either en or ar payload would be `{"row": {"LabebStoreId": d["LabebStoreId"], ...}}`

Comment: I have updated the pseudo code to make it more understandable.

Comment: So is `LabebStoreId`, `catalog_uuid` unique for each `en`/`ar`? You can group by these two columns.

Comment: `LabebStoreId` is same for all the products and `catalog_uuid' is unique for all the products but share the same uuid for `en/ar` version.

Comment: Can you update the sample data with more rows/products?

Comment: sure! just a sec

Comment: Done! I have updated both paired `en/ar` versions and the one which only contains one lang version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand correctly, you can group the data by `LabebStoreId` and `catalog_uuid` and then you make payloads according each group:

```py
import csv

data = {}
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault((row["LabebStoreId"], row["catalog_uuid"]), []).append(
            row
        )

for payload_no, v in enumerate(data.values(), 1):
    print("Payload number", payload_no)
    for d in v:
        print("Language", d["lang"])
        print("\t", d)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Payload number 1
Language en
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '89028', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Batteries', 'cat_3_name': 'Alkaline Batteries', 'catalogname': 'Energizer Max AA Alkaline Battery E91BP Pack of 8', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "Battery voltage": "1.5"}', 'price': '41.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
Language ar
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '89028', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة', 'cat_2_name': 'بطاريات', 'cat_3_name': 'بطاريات الكالاين', 'catalogname': 'ENERGIZER BATTERY AAX8 MAX', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "طاقة البطارية": "1.5"}', 'price': '41.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 2
Language en
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '742553', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Batteries', 'cat_3_name': 'Alkaline Batteries', 'catalogname': 'Energizer Max AAA Alkaline Battery EP2BP Pack of 8', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "Battery voltage": "1.5"}', 'price': '33.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
Language ar
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '742553', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة', 'cat_2_name': 'بطاريات', 'cat_3_name': 'بطاريات الكالاين', 'catalogname': 'ENERGIZER AAA/8 MAX ALKALINE', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "طاقة البطارية": "1.5"}', 'price': '33.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 3
Language en
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '893379', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Large Appliances', 'cat_2_name': 'Fridges', 'cat_3_name': 'Fridge 101L to 200L', 'catalogname': 'First1 Free Standing 2 shelves Fridge FR-130L', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Dimensions WxDxH": "W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm"}', 'price': '549.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': 'Free delivery', 'discount': '', 'instock': '1.0'}
Language ar
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '893379', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'أجهزة منزلية كبيرة', 'cat_2_name': 'الثلاجات', 'cat_3_name': 'ثلاجة 101L إلى 200L', 'catalogname': 'FIRST1 FR-130L FRIDGE', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Dimensions WxDxH": "W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm"}', 'price': '549.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': '1.0'}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 4
Language en
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '915909', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Power Adaptors & Sockets', 'cat_3_name': 'Adaptors & Sockets', 'catalogname': 'Elexon Universal Travel Adaptor PP7974A White', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '14.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/adaptors-sockets/elexon-universal-travel-adaptor/p/915909', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 5
Language en
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '945671', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Small Appliances', 'cat_2_name': 'Food Preparation', 'cat_3_name': 'Rice Cooker', 'catalogname': 'Mychoice Rice Cooker 350W F-06RC White', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '69.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
Language ar
         {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '945671', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'أجهزة منزلية صغيرة', 'cat_2_name': 'تحضير الطعام', 'cat_3_name': 'طبخ الأرز', 'catalogname': 'جهاز طهي الأرز الأول F-06RC 350 وات 0.6 لتر', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '69.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

To have `{'row':...}` or `{'row':..., 'nextRow':...}` you can check lenght of the group:

```py
import csv

data = {}
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault((row["LabebStoreId"], row["catalog_uuid"]), []).append(
            row
        )

for payload_no, v in enumerate(data.values(), 1):
    print("Payload number", payload_no)
    if len(v) == 1:
        payload = {"row": v[0]}
    else:
        payload = {"row": v[0], "nextRow": v[1]}

    print("\t", payload)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Payload number 1
         {'row': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '89028', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Batteries', 'cat_3_name': 'Alkaline Batteries', 'catalogname': 'Energizer Max AA Alkaline Battery E91BP Pack of 8', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "Battery voltage": "1.5"}', 'price': '41.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}, 'nextRow': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '89028', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة', 'cat_2_name': 'بطاريات', 'cat_3_name': 'بطاريات الكالاين', 'catalogname': 'ENERGIZER BATTERY AAX8 MAX', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "طاقة البطارية": "1.5"}', 'price': '41.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke91bp-batery-8-aa/p/89028', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 2
         {'row': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '742553', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Batteries', 'cat_3_name': 'Alkaline Batteries', 'catalogname': 'Energizer Max AAA Alkaline Battery EP2BP Pack of 8', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "Battery voltage": "1.5"}', 'price': '33.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}, 'nextRow': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '742553', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'البطاريات ومولدات الطاقة', 'cat_2_name': 'بطاريات', 'cat_3_name': 'بطاريات الكالاين', 'catalogname': 'ENERGIZER AAA/8 MAX ALKALINE', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Number of batteries included": "8", "طاقة البطارية": "1.5"}', 'price': '33.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/alkaline-batteries/energizer-max-alke92bp-batery-8-aaa/p/742553', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 3
         {'row': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '893379', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Large Appliances', 'cat_2_name': 'Fridges', 'cat_3_name': 'Fridge 101L to 200L', 'catalogname': 'First1 Free Standing 2 shelves Fridge FR-130L', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Dimensions WxDxH": "W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm"}', 'price': '549.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': 'Free delivery', 'discount': '', 'instock': '1.0'}, 'nextRow': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '893379', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'أجهزة منزلية كبيرة', 'cat_2_name': 'الثلاجات', 'cat_3_name': 'ثلاجة 101L إلى 200L', 'catalogname': 'FIRST1 FR-130L FRIDGE', 'description': '', 'properties': '{"Dimensions WxDxH": "W 49cm x D 45cm x H 83.5cm"}', 'price': '549.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/fridge-101l-to-200l/mychoice-first1-fridge-fr-130l-94l/p/893379', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': '1.0'}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 4
         {'row': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '915909', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Batteries & Power', 'cat_2_name': 'Power Adaptors & Sockets', 'cat_3_name': 'Adaptors & Sockets', 'catalogname': 'Elexon Universal Travel Adaptor PP7974A White', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '14.5', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/adaptors-sockets/elexon-universal-travel-adaptor/p/915909', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payload number 5
         {'row': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '945671', 'lang': 'en', 'cat_0_name': 'Electronics & Appliances', 'cat_1_name': 'Small Appliances', 'cat_2_name': 'Food Preparation', 'cat_3_name': 'Rice Cooker', 'catalogname': 'Mychoice Rice Cooker 350W F-06RC White', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '69.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/en/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}, 'nextRow': {'LabebStoreId': '6021', 'catalog_uuid': '945671', 'lang': 'ar', 'cat_0_name': 'الإلكترونيات والأجهزة المنزلية', 'cat_1_name': 'أجهزة منزلية صغيرة', 'cat_2_name': 'تحضير الطعام', 'cat_3_name': 'طبخ الأرز', 'catalogname': 'جهاز طهي الأرز الأول F-06RC 350 وات 0.6 لتر', 'description': '', 'properties': '{}', 'price': '69.0', 'price_before_discount': '', 'externallink': 'https://www.carrefouruae.com//mafuae/ar/rice-cooker/mychoice-first1-rice-cooker-f-06rc/p/945671', 'Rating': '', 'delivery': '', 'discount': '', 'instock': ''}}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How can I modify the payload depending on paired or not `{"row": {....}` and `{"nextRow": {...}` ?

Comment: Awesome! it worked as expected in a more clean way than I expected thank you so much @Andrej Kesely.

Comment: HI @Andrej Kesely I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761253/how-to-read-a-list-of-large-csv-files-in-optimized-way-in-python regarding reading the csv data chunkwise so it won't load all the data in memory at once. I was hoping if you have some time to take a look at it and help me through this it would be much appreciated. Thank you!